# optimizing redundant call on immutable objects

Tags: scala, jvm

Consider this scala code

```
val word = str.toLowerCase
val chars = word.distinct.sorted
```

and then later

```
//chars.map(c => str.toLowerCase.count(_ == c))
chars.map(c => word.count(_ == c))
```

I created the `val word` to avoid creating a new lower case string for map. But, in theory, can the Scala compiler optimize it away? It knows that strings are immutable.

Answer (score 7):

If the compiler somehow knew that `.toLowerCase` always returns the same result and does not have any side effects, it could optimize several calls to `.toLowerCase` on the same object to just one call. However, it can't know that and in your example it's not even true. For instance, depending on the default locale used, `"I".toLowerCase` might be `"i"` or `"ı"`. Since the default locale can change between calls, such an optimization would not be valid.

Comment: How come `str` can change if this is within one method?

Comment: I never said `str` can change.